# Terminal windows open with ["#Curl: command not found"]

Tags: command-line, bash, alias, curl

This seems to be related to my `~/.bash_aliases` file. The message only appears when I open a new terminal window and when I try source `~/.bash_aliases`. I've made sure CURL and all related libraries are installed and up to date, Ubuntu is updated to the latest programs on 14.04. All other aliases in `~/.bash_aliases` work fine. Any ideas?

Comment: [edit] your question and add the output of `cat ~/.bash_aliases`

Answer (score 1):

There is a line in your `~/.bash_aliases` that begins with `]#Curl`. This is invalid `bash` syntax. Edit, with the editor of your choice, `~/.bash_aliases`,
find the line beginning with `]#Curl` and remove the `]`. This will change the line to `#Curl ...`, which is a Bash comment line.